# Unity - Enemy AI; Run away from player (x and y)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, 2d, artificial-intelligence, unityscript

I need some help with creating a script for the enemies in my game! I'm making a 2.5D game where you chase campers and try to kill them. I'm mostly done with the game, but I can't get the AI to work! I've looked around for scripts and help for a couple of days now but can't find anything that fits well with the rest of my game... Please help!

For my ground i have a flat surface rotated at 35 on the x-axis, which have worked pretty well for me so far (moving the character around and placing obstacles).

At this point I'm working on this script;

```
#pragma strict

//Attack button
var attackButton : Joystick;

var anim : Animator;
var delay = 5.0;

//Player can kill
var CanKill = false;

//Score
var scoreValue : int;
var killValue : int;
var playerControl : PlayerControl;

//AI
var speed : int = 2;
var Damp: float = 1.0;

var isRun: boolean = false;
var Target: Transform;

var detectionRange: int = 5;

private var character : CharacterController;

function Start () 
{

    anim = GetComponent("Animator");
    var playerControlObject : GameObject = GameObject.FindWithTag ("Player");

    character = GetComponent(CharacterController);


}

function WaitAndDestroy()
{

    yield WaitForSeconds(delay);
        Destroy (gameObject);

}

function Update()
{

    //Can the player kill?
    if (attackButton.tapCount == 1)
        CanKill = true;

    else CanKill = false; 

    //AI
    var FromPlayer =  Vector3(Target.position.x - transform.position.x, 0);

        if(FromPlayer.magnitude <= detectionRange){
            isRun = true;
        }

        if(FromPlayer.magnitude >= detectionRange) {
            isRun = false;
        }

        if(isRun) {
            RunAway();
            anim.SetBool("Walk", true);
        }

        else anim.SetBool("Walk", false);


}

function OnTriggerEnter (Other : Collider){

    if(Other.gameObject.tag == "Player" && CanKill == true) {
        playerControl.AddScore (scoreValue);
        playerControl.AddKills (killValue);
        anim.SetTrigger("Dead");
        WaitAndDestroy();
    }

}

function RunAway()
{

    var moveDirection : Vector3 = transform.position;
    character.Move(moveDirection.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime);

}`
```

Which kinda works, but for some reason the character stops in the middle of the level and just runs in place... I would also like him to turn and run the other direction if I (the player) catches him and runs in front of him. (If the code is a little messy I apologize, but as I said I'm new to Javascript).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the campers to run away from the player right? Then you should do

```
Vector3 moveDirection = transform.position - Player.transform.position
```

To get the direction they should run in. Then do the line you already have

```
character.Move(moveDirection.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

Comment: Would this make them run on both the x and y axis?

Comment: transform.position is a Vector3 so yes. By subtracting the player's position from the camper's position you get the difference between the 2 positions in 3d space (and if the z axis is the same for both then it's just a 2d difference). This resulting vector, after being normalized, is the direction that the camper should run in to get away from the player.

Comment: This works to an extent, but the moveDirection line you gave me cause the camper to run  through the ground, for some reason...

Comment: That means the Z axis of the player and the camper are not the same. Try setting the Z value of moveDirection to the current Z value before normalizing it. In C# it's moveDirection = new Vector3(moveDirection.x, moveDirection.y, transform.position.z); I'm not familiar with javascript but it could be as simple as moveDirection.z = transform.position.z;

Comment: That worked! The camper now collides with the ground, the only problem now is that he sticks to the bottom of the hill, only running along the x-axis. I'll probably figure it out sooner or later though, thanks a million for all your help!

Comment: If you have hills then that is a problem. Your CharacterController.Move method should ideally be able to accept a direction (like the Vector3 result of player - camper) and handle moving up/down hills automatically. Unity has methods that let you do so but I'm not too familiar with them, so I can't help. My answer by itself does not work for hills, only for flat terrain... or for things floating in 3d space without collision.

Answer (score 1):

i would done those two changes.

At first:

```
var FromPlayer =  transform.position - Player.transform.position;
```

cause you want subtract whole vectors not just x coordinates
and second:

```
function RunAway( FromPlayer :vector3 )
{
    character.Move(FromPlayer.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

if you have already vector `FromPlayer` you can directly use it for moving character

i personally never used unity but that is how you would done it anywhere else. It of course assume that positions can be substracted as vectors

Comment: Could you elaborate on your FromPlayer line? It doesn't make much sense to me since the Player IS the Target in my script.

Comment: oh ok, transform is the enemy? and you are Target?

Comment: This script is attached to the camper (enemy). The Target is set to the Player (me). I'm not sure who you mean 'transform' should be, sorry. I'll take a look at this though, see if it'll work, thanks!

Comment: I see, than it of course goes to the same solution as the one below. Good luck